# Swift NSHTTPCookieStorage count:2

Tags: swift, count, nshttpcookiestorage

```
var httpCookie:NSHTTPCookieStorage=NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage();
println(httpCookie)

<NSHTTPCookieStorage cookies count:2>
```

How can I loop it each a cookie?

Answer (score 4):

look at this code

```
var cookies:[NSHTTPCookie] = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies as [NSHTTPCookie]
for cookie:NSHTTPCookie in cookies as [NSHTTPCookie] {
    if cookie.name as String == "CookieName" {
        var cookieValue : String = "CookieName=" + cookie.value! as String

        //if you want to add to your request
        youRequest.setValue(cookieValue, forHTTPHeaderField: "cookie")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `URLSession` in **Swift 5** a concise way to loop through the returned Cookies...

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, resp, error) in

if let response = resp as? HTTPURLResponse {
    print("Status Code \(response.statusCode)")

    if let cookies:[HTTPCookie] = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies{
        for cookie:HTTPCookie in cookies as [HTTPCookie] {
            // logic here...
        }
    }
}
```

Remember, cookies may already be inside the store.  If you want a solid count, make sure - before you send the request -  to clean up the Cookie store...

```
HTTPCookieStorage.shared.deleteCookie(cookie: HTTPCookie)
```